# Google map with multiple locations, URL only

Tags: maps, google-maps-markers

I know the similar question was asked before, but I couldn't find a proper answer. I need to show on Google dynamic maps several markers without Javascript, URL only. It can be easily done with Yandex maps like [that](https://yandex.ru/maps/?key=AMvRalUBAAAAo7FSQgIAAXpgmsD4Jdn1PjP0k4TPPVSPkaUAAAAAAAAAAAAoQf7UcZ7Akj-S-KprTfAwIFT7tw%3D%3D&ll=37.9704106944444%2C44.5669543055556&spn=0.0067%2C0.0041&l=sat&pt=37.9690933333333%2C44.5673525%2Cpmrds1~37.9737402777778%2C44.5678777777778%2Cpmbls2~37.9735211111111%2C44.5678091666667%2Cpmbls3~37.9733088888889%2C44.5677175%2Cpmbls4~37.9730936111111%2C44.5676291666667%2Cpmbls5~37.9728761111111%2C44.5675438888889%2Cpmbls6~37.9726516666667%2C44.567465%2Cpmbls7~37.9724380555556%2C44.567375%2Cpmbls8~37.9722308333333%2C44.5672761111111%2Cpmbls9~37.9720402777778%2C44.5671633333333%2Cpmbls10~37.9718563888889%2C44.5670452777778%2Cpmbls11~37.9716827777778%2C44.5669180555556%2Cpmbls12~37.9715138888889%2C44.5667869444444%2Cpmbls13~37.9713525%2C44.56665%2Cpmbls14~37.9712069444444%2C44.5665055555556%2Cpmbls15~37.9710569444444%2C44.5663633333333%2Cpmbls16~37.9709025%2C44.5662236111111%2Cpmbls17~37.9707630555556%2C44.5660769444444%2Cpmbls18~37.9706227777778%2C44.56593%2Cpmbls19~37.9704875%2C44.5657780555556%2Cpmbls20~37.9703497222222%2C44.5656275%2Cpmbls21~37.9702022222222%2C44.5654863888889%2Cpmbls22~37.9700411111111%2C44.56535%2Cpmbls23~37.9698811111111%2C44.5652138888889%2Cpmbls24~37.9697083333333%2C44.5650838888889%2Cpmbls25~37.9695055555556%2C44.5649833333333%2Cpmbls26~37.9693005555556%2C44.5648847222222%2Cpmbls27~37.9729986111111%2C44.5688472222222%2Cpmbls28~37.9727588888889%2C44.568865%2Cpmbls29~37.9725233333333%2C44.5689063888889%2Cpmbls30~37.9722741666667%2C44.5689163888889%2Cpmbls31~37.9720288888889%2C44.5689319444444%2Cpmbls32~37.97178%2C44.5689477777778%2Cpmbls33~37.9715336111111%2C44.5689605555556%2Cpmbls34~37.9712852777778%2C44.5689638888889%2Cpmbls35~37.9710369444444%2C44.5689708333333%2Cpmbls36~37.9707886111111%2C44.5689813888889%2Cpmbls37~37.9705405555556%2C44.5689947222222%2Cpmbls38~37.9702925%2C44.5690097222222%2Cpmbls39~37.9700452777778%2C44.5690158333333%2Cpmbls40~37.969795%2C44.5690238888889%2Cpmbls41~37.9695458333333%2C44.5690127777778%2Cpmbls42~37.9692966666667%2C44.5690025%2Cpmbls43~37.9690477777778%2C44.5689830555556%2Cpmbls44~37.9687986111111%2C44.5689647222222%2Cpmbls45~37.9685494444444%2C44.5689469444444%2Cpmbls46~37.9683027777778%2C44.5689313888889%2Cpmbls47~37.9680555555556%2C44.5689183333333%2Cpmbls48~37.9678144444444%2C44.5688747222222%2Cpmbls49~37.9675763888889%2C44.5688194444444%2Cpmbls50~37.9673283333333%2C44.5687894444444%2Cpmbls51~37.9670811111111%2C44.5687833333333%2Cpmbls52~37.9672316666667%2C44.5688213888889%2Cpmbls53~37.9730688888889%2C44.5686161111111%2Cpmbls54~37.9728275%2C44.5685769444444%2Cpmbls55~37.972585%2C44.5685405555556%2Cpmbls56~37.9723422222222%2C44.5685030555556%2Cpmbls57~37.9721011111111%2C44.5684675%2Cpmbls58~37.9718575%2C44.5684325%2Cpmbls59~37.9716130555556%2C44.5683983333333%2Cpmbls60~37.9713705555556%2C44.5683677777778%2Cpmbls61~37.9711286111111%2C44.5683322222222%2Cpmbls62~37.9708844444444%2C44.5683030555556%2Cpmbls63~37.9706408333333%2C44.5682716666667%2Cpmbls64~37.9703980555556%2C44.5682430555556%2Cpmbls65~37.9701544444444%2C44.5682163888889%2Cpmbls66~37.9699102777778%2C44.5681894444444%2Cpmbls67~37.9696644444444%2C44.5681636111111%2Cpmbls68~37.9694205555556%2C44.5681388888889%2Cpmbls69~37.9691719444444%2C44.5681161111111%2Cpmbls70~37.9689252777778%2C44.5680938888889%2Cpmbls71~37.9686772222222%2C44.5680713888889%2Cpmbls72~37.9684294444444%2C44.5680519444444%2Cpmbls73~37.9681805555556%2C44.5680413888889%2Cpmbls74~37.9679333333333%2C44.5680163888889%2Cpmbls75~37.9676877777778%2C44.5679891666667%2Cpmbls76~37.9674441666667%2C44.5679611111111%2Cpmbls77~37.9672072222222%2C44.5679583333333%2Cpmbls78~37.9673327777778%2C44.5679897222222%2Cpmbls79), but how to do the same with Google?

Answer (score 0):

The nearest solution that I have for you is using Googles [My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/about/mymaps/), It allows you to create your custom map by adding markers, Importing data using a spreadsheet.

You can share the map by embedding it on your website by clicking on the share button which produces an iFrame tag.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I need to create an URL link to the map dynamically using points' coordinates from the program, not on the web site.